# TCP/IP Setting up a connection/what makes a connection

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

This is just a general question.

In TCP/IP when you set up a connection between two points you do a 3 way hand shake.

Do you have to re do this every time you change the source port and/or destination port?

I.e lets say you set up a connection from ip A to ip B and source port s to source port d. Now you want to send a packet from source port s to a new source port e. Do you have to establish another connection here again?

Or do you only establish the connection when you first encounter the ip addresses?

THANKS GOT IT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A connection in TCP is identified by the 4-tuple *(source-ip, source-port, destination-ip, destination-port)*. Therefore, connecting to a different port on the same machine requires you to establish a new TCP connection.

Consider that it is possible, through NAT and other routing tricks, for requests to different ports on the same IP address to go to different machines anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Connection is between two particular pairs of IP:port. Each peer connection object stores this info, so when you send data to the connected endpoint this info is used to form IP packet. There's no way to change this info so you need to reestablish connection if you need to connect to another IP or port.

Answer (score 0):

"Do you have to re do this every time you change the source port and/or destination port?" Yes. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcp_protocol#Connection_establishment) Wikipedia article. The reason behind this is that different IP addresses usually identify different hosts on the network, and different TCP ports usually identify different applications, or different functionalities of the same application.

Answer (score 0):

A TCP connection is a network stream service between a server socket, (IP and port) and a client socket, (IP and port). Any attempt to change any element of this socket-pair implies that the previous connection is broken and a new connection needs to be established before streaming can proceed.